# Why, according to Adorno, were Schoenberg's innovations progressive?

Tags: aesthetics, critical-theory, adorno

I think that Zuidervaart, in his book *Adorno's aesthetic theory*, says that Adorno makes two claims for artworks:

1. They develop the productive forces of the artform
2. The artist has a cognition of the social whole

The book has no preview, and I can never find it, so I cannot find quotes right now... But, rather than establish the role of these two claims in Adorno's aesthetics, I would really like to know what 1 *really means*.

Is there a simple (i.e. freely available) criteria for when something is a regressive development of the artform (as in, failing to meet point 1), or is that something which the critic has to decide based on their (presumably) subjective preferences?

i.e., **why does Schoenberg's music meet this requirement (according to Zuidervaart / Adorno) and not Stravinsky's?**

FWIW, I would imagine that newness, as we normally conceive of it, is not enough. Or an increase in *complexity*. If forced to guess, I'd draw an analogy with technology, and suggest that the emancipation of dissonance made something in the compositional process more powerful -- more *totalising*.